# Java open-source for workflow management

Tags: open-source, java

I'm planning to develop an application and need a workflow engine as well for couple of process, approval, rejection, etc.

Please kindly recommend a good Java open-source workflow management tool or library or software to integrate with Java app.

Comment: Do you need it to be compatible with any workflow standard, or any workflow editor?

Comment: Also, what does "best"/"good" mean for you? Please sort these terms in order of importance to you: user-friendly, full-featured, well-documented, popular, thread-safe, resilient, well-tooled, frequently updated.

Comment: Looking for customizable, workflow editor, well-documented, forums and support available for any queries. that's all which i want

Answer (score 0):

Check below software which are free and open source written in java and can be integrate with a java application.

1. [Activiti](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti)
2. [Camunda](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform)
3. [Flowable](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine)

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions. Is all of them support CRUD operation with default search options or filter options for any table or entity defined ? if anyone of them has it by default, please let me know. that would be helpful. can you share more info on the above if possible about differences and pros and cons.

Comment: Actually I have just ran them and checked only basic scenarios for my purposes. There are good set of documentation on these apps. You can refer the docs whether to check the your use case can be fulfilled or not.

Comment: Can u please suggest one based on your experience?

Comment: Both Camunda and Flowable are forks of activiti. But both of them provide additional features in open source project. The decision to use which one is really depend on your use case.